# How to use the local Dockerrun.aws.json file while creating application version? (aws cli)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

Currently I am using the following cli command to create the application version in aws

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name $APPLICATION_NAME --version-label $VERSION_LABEL --description $VERSION_LABEL --source-bundle S3Bucket=$S3_BUCKET,S3Key=$S3_KEY
```

Here this command is depended on the s3.

Actually the Dockerrun.aws.json exist in my local, How to use the local Dockerrun.aws.json while creating the application version

I have tried the following code

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name $APPLICATION_NAME --version-label $VERSION_LABEL --description $VERSION_LABEL --option-settings file://Dockerrun.aws.json
```

It is showing some error

> usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
>   To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help
>
> aws <command> help
>
> aws <command> <subcommand> help
>
> Unknown options: --option-settings, file://Dockerrun.aws.json

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use [`eb` CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) to deploy your Dockerfile.aws.json to Elastic Beanstalk.

To make it work you need to configure `eb` to deploy an artifact -- Dockerfile.aws.json -- instead of an archive of source directory. See details in  the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact).

The similar issue has been discussed here: [Deploy to elasticbeanstalk via CLI deploy command with Dockerrun.aws.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833184/deploy-to-elasticbeanstalk-via-cli-deploy-command-with-dockerrun-aws-json)

**Edit:**

You cannot do it the way you want to with AWS CLI. `create-application-version` requires that the source bundle is available either in S3, CodeCommit, or CodeBuild. This is explicitly stated [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-application-version.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateApplicationVersion.html).

Comment: thank you @Olli is there any way to do it using "aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version " command ?